# Navigation Item in XIB file is not visible

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder, xcode7

I'm in XCode 7.2.1 and I am trying to make a view that is reusable and should have some custom elements in the navigation bar.

If I would add a view to my storyboard, connect it via a segue to the navigation controller and make sure there is a "Navigation Item" in the view, I could see the navigation bar and edit my items in it.

If I manually add a `Navigation Item` to a XIB however I can't see anything. Even if I switch in the simulated metrics settings `Top Bar` to something else than `Inferred` or `None`.

I don't want to use the storyboard, if possible. Is there a descent way to make the navigation item visible and edit it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you link your View Controller correctly with Navigation Controller. When you link it, you should choose with `root View Controller`. If you link it correctly, you don't have to add `NavigationItem` manually.

By the way, you shouldn't do the customization for Navigation bar directly in xib. All you can do is only to set the `Title`, `Prompt` and `Back Button` text.

Do it in code! I think you won't have different styles for navigation bar in different views, right? That would be too silly.